# booting Fedora from USB taking forever

Tags: linux, boot, usb, fedora

I am trying to install Fedora 21 workstation from a .iso usb drive and it is taking forever. It allows me to select the live workstation, and then the white diagonal fill line goes up until it is about 80% to the top and then it just hangs. I have tried this on 2 different USB's and they both hang at the same spot. I've been sitting here for like 20 minutes with it hanging there and that seems unreasonably long for it to boot.

This is my first time booting from USB (cannot for the life of me find my blank CD's), so I'm not sure what to expect. Is this normal?

FYI - using an intel i7 4790k with ASROCK extreme6/ac mobo.

EDIT: Just used the USB on a spare laptop and it booted right away (no hanging) - what could be going on with my setup? It's a brand new desktop build.

Comment: Since it boot correctly on the laptop the only problem I can think of is a driver problem. I produce my Linux sticks with my own procedure and never had any problems ==> https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=475A0A48CA6D4035&id=475A0A48CA6D4035%211947 The data partition part is optional but I like it because I use this large stick mainly for recovering data from dead systems of my friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reconnected the SATA cables in a different order and it cleared things up. I had my optical drive in a higher priority (I think) than one of my HDDs. I have no idea why this would cause a problem, but I put my optical drive in the lowest priority and it magically worked.